# No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere-liberty

I am using **IBM Liberty 16.0.0.4**

I am trying to call webservice through generated client classed using wsimport, but when i try to call endpoint service i got next WARNINGs and ERROR.

```
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportBinding registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportToken registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}HttpsToken registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}AlgorithmSuite registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Basic256 registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Layout registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Lax registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}IncludeTimestamp registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedSupportingTokens registered.
[WARNING ] No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}UsernameToken registered.
[ERROR   ] None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

Do you know if i need to add extra jars or what is my real problem? or what is missing?

Note: i added **Security** with **UsernameToken** which have the *username* and *password* in custom SOAPHandler

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on enabling **wsSecurity** on Liberty server and it needs to be enabled explicitly.

so i used wsSecurity-1.1 inside `<featureManager>`

```
<feature>wsSecurity-1.1</feature>
```

Also for sending credentials of username and password i was need to use next code for UsernameToken

```
Map ctx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.username", "username");
ctx.put("ws-security.password", "password");
```

And not just adding UsernameToken into header using security SOAP element like that

> security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");

*References*

> 1-
>   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_wssec_msglvl.html
>
> 2-
>   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_wssec_cxf_diff.html